# Not executing correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop, syntax-error

So I'm making a  poll program that will take all of the choices (a or b) and tole them into a percentage. It all works but the output (Pictures below) Any help would be most appreciated.[image: The result]

The problem lies somewhere in here but i can't find it 
         for(int at=0;at Answere_1) then sets it to a ratio 
             {
                 System.out.println(at);
                 if(y[at] > y[at+1])
                 {
                     y[at] /= counter;
                     y[at]=Math.round(y[at] * 100.0) / 100.0;
                     y[at+1] = 1- y[at];
                     y[at+1]=Math.round(y[at+1] * 100.0) / 100.0;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     y[at+1] /= counter;
                     y[at+1]=Math.round(y[at+1] * 100.0) / 100.0;
                     y[at] =  1- y[at+1];
                     y[at]=Math.round(y[at] * 100.0) / 100.0;

```
             }
         }

         String output = "";
         for (int i=0; i<size; i+=2)
         {
            output += x[i] +" <- "+ y[i] +"  "+ x[i+1] +" -> "+ y[i+1] + "\n";
         }
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);   
     }
  }
```

}
}

So it seems that it is not running through all of the results, or it is not calculating them but i can't find out why

Comment: Could you provide less code and tell us what's not working ? What did you try ?

Comment: Is the problem related to Swing? If no then consider posting code which will use only console. it will be way shorter (since we will get rid of unnecessary swing code). And please get rid of these escape ``\`` escape characters before `[` and `]` (SO doesn't treat these braces as special characters inside code blocks).

Comment: I see you don't have `editor` badge in your profile, which means you never edited your post. To do so use [edit] option below your post.

Comment: I figured it out thanks for the help anyways :)